# Convergence fails for an example

Tags: python, neural-network

I am following the book, 'Make your own neural network' and https://sudeepraja.github.io/Neural/ . I am doing the neural network without numpy, scipy, scikitlearn etc. I am trying to check if my algorithm is correct by training the following network using same input-output combination multiple times. However, no matter how many steps I take or increase the loop counter, the network isn't learning the output at all.

*I hope the code is readable as I am assuming that the code is transliteration of the github source.*

Specifically the value of first output neuron never changes (ideally, it should converge to 0.01 but is stuck at 0.5). The code is available at http://tpcg.io/ruufxJ and presented below in case the link expires. I've also tried https://github.com/Horopter/NeuralNetworks-2018/blob/master/NeuralNetwork.py but the code is just wrong over there [doesn't scale up to multiple layers]

```
import math,copy

def initArrZero(num):
    l = []
    for i in range(num):
        l.append(0)
    return l

def initMatrix(rows,cols):
    m = []
    for i in range(rows):
        m.append(initArrZero(cols))
    return m    

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0/(1.0 + math.e**(-x))

def sigmoid_m(x):
    if isinstance(x,list):
        lst = []
        for i in x:
            lst.append(sigmoid_m(i))
        return lst
    else:
        return sigmoid(x)

def sigmoid_prime(x):
    return sigmoid(x)*(1-sigmoid(x))

def sigmoid_prime_m(x):
    if isinstance(x,list):
        lst = []
        for i in x:
            lst.append(sigmoid_prime_m(i))
        return lst
    else:
        return sigmoid_prime(x)

def transpose(m):
    return [[m[j][i] for j in range(len(m))] for i in range(len(m[0]))]

def matmul(A,B):
    result = initMatrix(len(A),len(B[0]))
    for i in range(len(A)):  
        for j in range(len(B[0])): 
            for k in range(len(B)): 
                result[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
    return result

def matadd(X,Y):
    result = copy.deepcopy(X)
    for i in range(len(X)): 
        for j in range(len(X[0])): 
            result[i][j] = X[i][j] + Y[i][j]
    return result

def hadamard(X,Y):
    result = copy.deepcopy(X)
    for i in range(len(X)): 
        for j in range(len(X[0])): 
            result[i][j] = X[i][j] * Y[i][j]
    return result

def scalarmul(A,B):
    if isinstance(A,list) and (isinstance(B,float) or isinstance(B,int)):
        return scalarmul(B,A)
    if isinstance(B,list):
        lst = []
        for i in B:
            lst.append(scalarmul(A,i))
        return lst
    return A*B

def subtract(A,B):
    if isinstance(A,list) and isinstance(B,list) and len(A)==len(B):
        lst = []
        for i in range(len(A)):
            lst.append(subtract(A[i],B[i]))
        return lst
    else:
        return A-B

class NN:
    def __init__(self,arr):
        assert len(arr)>1
        l = len(arr)
        input = initArrZero(arr[0]+1)
        input[-1] = 1
        self.layers = []
        self.layers.append(input)
        for i in range(1,l-1):
            lst = initArrZero(arr[i])
            self.layers.append(lst)
        self.layers.append(initArrZero(arr[-1]))

        self.weights = []
        for i in range(l-1):
            w = initMatrix(len(self.layers[i]),len(self.layers[i+1]))
            self.weights.append(w)

    def feedforward(self):
        for i in range(0,len(self.layers)-1):
            self.layers[i+1] = sigmoid_m(matmul(self.weights[i],self.layers[i]))

    def backprop(self,actual,alpha):
        self.wd = initArrZero(len(self.weights))
        self.wdm = initArrZero(len(self.weights))

        for i in range(len(self.weights)-1,-1,-1):
            if i == len(self.weights)-1:
                self.wd[i] = hadamard(subtract(self.layers[-1],actual),sigmoid_prime_m(matmul(self.weights[-1],self.layers[-2])))
            else:
                self.wd[i] = hadamard(matmul(transpose(self.weights[i+1]),self.wd[i+1]),sigmoid_prime_m(matmul(self.weights[i],self.layers[i])))

        for i in range(len(self.weights)-1,-1,-1):
            t = transpose(self.layers[i])
            self.wdm[i] = matmul(self.wd[i],t)

        for i in range(len(self.weights)-1,-1,-1):
            self.weights[i] = matadd(self.weights[i],hadamard(scalarmul(-1*alpha,self.weights[i]),self.wdm[i]))

    def show(self):
        print "Layers : "
        for p in self.layers:
            print p

        print "\n\n\n"

        print "Weights : "
        for i in range(len(self.weights)):
            print self.weights[i]

        print "\n\n\n"

n = NN([2,2,2])
n.layers[0] = [[0.05],[0.1],[1]]
n.weights[0] = transpose([[0.15,0.25],[0.2,0.3],[0.35,0.6]])
n.weights[1] = transpose([[0.4,0.5],[0.45,0.55]])
n.show()
for i in range(1000):
    n.feedforward()
    n.backprop([[0.01],[0.99]],5)
n.show()
```

Expected : last layer is close to `(0.01,0.99)`

Output : `(0.5, 0.9892866637557137)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigmoid acivation usually performs badly. If the value you feed in is very high or very low, the slope is almost flat, i.e.: little-to-no learning.
You can try a couple of solutions:

1) change the initialization of your weights.

2) change activation function (suggested). You can try activations that typically perform much better, such as ReLU or leaky-ReLU.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually I've tried training an XOR neural network but it failed as well. I'm wondering if the program I wrote has any bugs. I'll try using leaky RELU and post my results here. Is there a sample set I could train with sigmoid activation to check if I did my code right?

Comment: Nope! Tried with ReLU and leaky ReLU. I think there's something wrong with my math. If it's not too much to ask, could anyone please get back to me w.r.t. 
 math/code?

Comment: Sorry to hear this. Since walking through other's code is very complicated, can you set up a debugger?
If you're using plain Python, you can use the pdb library, waltk through the execution step by step, and understand what is the function that is causing problems. That's the first step to solve your problem.
I usually do: `from pdb import set_trace as bp`, and then put a break point `bp()` where I need in the code. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much Ivan! It cleared up that my code is doing what it is expected to do. However, I am confused because, I am wondering if a neural network can learn a small data set with sigmoid activation function at all. I am gonna give another shot with leaky ReLU as I've been told that I was implementing it the wrong way and I'll get back here.

Comment: Learning from small datasets is difficult not just for neural networks, but for any ML algorithm. What is the size of your dataset?
On the activation function: to my knowledge, every single course that I followed, and every single book that I've read, they *all* agreed that sigmoid performs worse than other activation functions in general. However, you can still get good results by sticking to sigmoid. Try more than one if you can, and pick the one that works best!